# Return value and close window using only ASP.NET code

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I want to know, how can I set the return value, and close windows, using only C# code behind an ASP.NET button ?

In JavaScript, this would be done thru this code:

```
sendObj = {okpressed: false, movementYearValue: '',vestingFileBrowseValue: ''};
window.returnValue = sendObj;
window.close();
```

However, because the values I want to send are C# code dependent, I have to do the above functionality from within C# code ..

I know how to close the window from C# code, but I don't know how to return values using C# code ..

Comment: you can use viewstate

Answer (score 0):

On the C# side, you can do this (the code basically dumps the javascript code into the aspx page):

```
string script = "sendObj = {okpressed: false, movementYearValue: '',vestingFileBrowseValue: ''};";
script += "window.returnValue = sendObj;";
script += "window.close();";

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", script);
```